# Avoid double recursion

Tags: recursion, lisp

```
(DEFUN F(L)
   (COND
      ((NULL L) NIL)
      ((LISTP (CAR L))
       (APPEND (F (CAR L))
               (F (CDR L))
               (CAR (F (CAR L)))))
      (T (LIST (CAR L)))
))
```

This function returns a dotted pair(if the first element is a sublist) with the first element of the sublist as the right part and on the left part are the element on the right and the second element of the list(if not sublist).Now,how can I rewrite this without using the double recursion of `(F (CAR L))` and without using `SET,SETQ,SETF`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LET` to bind a local variable to the repeated recursive call.

```
(DEFUN F(L)
   (COND
      ((NULL L) NIL)
      ((LISTP (CAR L))
       (LET ((FCAR (F CAR L)))
         (APPEND FCAR
                 (F (CDR L))
                 (CAR FCAR))))
      (T (LIST (CAR L)))
))
```